# Internet Explorer: Start Internet Explorer 9 in Internet Explorer 7 mode as default

Tags: internet-explorer

Is there any way to set Internet Explorer 7 browser + document mode as default startup mode for Internet Explorer 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open internet explorer.
2. Click on Alt key on the keyboard. Now click on Tools in menu bar.
3. Select Compatibility View Settings.
4. Check Display all websites in Compatibility View.

Comment: Okay, but this makes the browser mode "ie9 compat view". Is this any different from ie7 compat view?